# SInt8 not recognized in Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, types

I have a project where I'm using some code from the aurioTouch sample project. For some reason, any line with the SInt8 type keeps on giving me a "Parse Issue: Unknown type SInt8" error. I have no idea what's causing this as this should be built into the iPhone SDK.

Is there something I may be overlooking that could cause this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: SInt8 is part of CoreFoundation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SInt8 is part of CoreFoundation. You have to

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

to get access to it, along with UInt8, SInt16, UInt16, etc.

Comment: You are right. +1 to you. Deleted my wrong answer. Curiously if it's part of core foundation he should have gotten it just by including foundation or cocoa headers!

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks a lot!